How to get a label value from another metric and add it on prometheus
Suppose a metric is like the following,
weblogic_id(domain="name", instance="instance"}
Is there any way I can get the domain="name" from that metric and add it to all other metrics of that started with weblgic_?
for example,
if a metric is like this
weblogic_server_listen_port{instance="instance",name="name"}
then it will be
weblogic_server_listen_port{domain="name", instance="instance",name="name"}
Thanks

On which level would you like to do that? Where do you want to use the label and "add" it to the other metrics? In the scrape config? Before scraping? After scraping? In Grafana? PromQL? ..

Hi, on prometheus end. using prometheus rules, scrape config or other means. but yeah any solution will be welcome. Thanks

Does this answer your question? How can I 'join' two metrics in a Prometheus query?

I think you should look at this -
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches
In the given example, you should have the source metric (in this case weblogic_id) with value as always as 1 since its going to be info metric. e.g. in node exporter, we have node_uname_info which provides various common labels  like nodename which can be used for other metrics using vector mapping.
So this is how it will look -
weblogic_info{domain="name", instance="instance"} 1
weblogic_server_listen_port{instance="instance",name="name"} 8080

rule or query in grafana (not tested so might need some tweaks) ->
weblogic_info * on(instance) group_left weblogic_server_listen_port

The resulting metric should have domain label.
Hope this helps!

Why have you changed metric name from weblogic_id to weblogic_info? Also, are you sure in the assumption that I'd will always be 1?

I'd suggest weblogic_server_listen_port + on(instance) group_left weblogic_id * 0

Yeah that’s the problem I was facing. whenever I use a vector matching it was always replacing the left side one. Thanks to markalex as the value will not be always 0, we can make it to look like zero by multiplying it with 0.

Also another thing, I know we can use vector matches to concat two metrics but can we contact a metric with all other metric on the go with vector match? for example: like this one weblogic_* + on(instance) group_left weblogic_id*0 I mean I want to add the domain name to all the metrics on the go.

@markalex that was an example, he needs to introduce that info metric with value 1 in his collector or use any similar metric which fits the definition
